# AWS CDK: Running Flask App on EC2 startup

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have a flask app listening to incoming POST requests as follows-

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/processpayload', methods=["POST"])
def handler():
    return "SUCCESSFULLY HITTING FLASK SERVER"


app.run(debug=True)
```

It is configured using NGINX for reverse proxy and everything is working fine.
But everytime i need to run this script , i have to ssh or enter into the console and do

```
python3 <filename>.py
```

and then the flask app starts listening for requests.

Is there a way to embed a script in userdata itself so that it runs automatically on cdk deploy and i do not have to everytime ssh into my instance and run it manually ?

I've tried using `python3 <name>.py`in my userdata ,but it does not start everytime the instance is deployed

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would setup `systemd` unit file for that, and probably use `Gunicorn` to run your flask app. You could skip `Gunicorn`, and just run flask directly using systemd. One example of how to set it up is here:

- [How To Serve Flask Applications with Gunicorn and Nginx on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Alternatively, run your flask through ElasticBeanstalk, which automatically [sets up everything](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html) for you flask.